# Consistent 'CS0201' error a in Unity3D engine class where there should not be

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I keep getting: Only assignment, call , increment etc... can be used as a statement (Its error code is CS0201). I get it on three lines:
I am using Unity3D and mono-develop. The class that i'm working in is abstract and the other class (which these variables' types are) is of the type AITarget.

```
target.Clear;
visualThreat.Clear;
audioThreat.Clear;
```

^ In 'AIStateMachine' class

I have checked the Clear method and it looks like this:

```
public void Clear(){
    type = AITargetType.None;
    collider = null;
    position = Vector3.zero;
    distance = 0.0f;
    time = Mathf.Infinity;
}
```

^ In AITarget class

When I created the AITargets:

```
protected AITarget target = new AITarget ();
public AITarget visualThreat = new AITarget();
public AITarget audioThreat = new AITarget();
```

^In AIStateMachine class

I am not using and == instead of =. I need help! (The type of error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Clear()` is a method but isn't being called as such. Change the following:

```
target.Clear;
visualThreat.Clear;
audioThreat.Clear;
```

To:

```
target.Clear();
visualThreat.Clear();
audioThreat.Clear();
```

Comment: I'm unsure what you want me to do. I have them all in different methods. Thanks for the quick reply though!

Comment: Wherever you have a call to `target.Clear;` change it to `target.Clear();` and so on for the other calls that are giving you the error. I updated the answer, hopefully it's more clear.

Comment: In C# you have to add parentheses to make it a method call, `target.Clear()` is a method call, `target.Clear` is a method, the compiler refuses to accept that as a statement. So add parentheses.

Comment: Thank you soooo much!!!! I thought It was that my head at one point but it slipped!